# Executing SQL Statement by getting Boolean Java

Tags: java, sql, jframe

I have 2 Frames let's name them "Request" and "Confirm". Now when clicking a Button in "Request" the Frame "Confirm" is called. And when clicking "yes" a SQL Statement should be executed. The thing is that the SQL Statement is in class "Request". The Class "Confirm" should be called from other Frames too, so I don't want to make an Action Listener on the Button "yes" in "Confirm". I what to get a boolen by clicking the "yes" Button. If its true the statement in 'Request" should be executed. 
How I can do this?

```
ReqBnt.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getSource() == ReqBnt) {

                String VendN = txtVendN.getText();
                String VendSN = txtVendSN.getText();
                String Ad = txtAd.getText();
                String Ads = txtAds.getText();
                String City = txtCity.getText();
                String Zip = txtZip.getText();
                String UID = txtUID.getText();
                String Reg = txtReg.getText();
                String Rep = txtRep.getText();
                String Tel = txtTel.getText();
                String Fax = txtFax.getText();
                String Mail = txtMail.getText();
                String Iban = txtIban.getText();
                String Bic = txtBic.getText();
                String BInst = txtBInst.getText();
                String VendInfo = txtVendInfo.getText();
                String Flag = "Y";
                String PT = comboPT.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String Ctry = comboCtry.getSelectedItem().toString();
            try{
                try {
                     String sqlx = "SELECT `Abbreviation 2`, `Country English` From `database`.`country_master` " + 
                             "WHERE `Country English` = '" + Ctry + "'";
                     PreparedStatement pstx = conn.prepareStatement(sqlx);
                     ResultSet rs = pstx.executeQuery();
                     while (rs.next()){
                      partCode = rs.getString("Abbreviation 2");
                        }}catch (Exception ex) {
                            System.out.println("Abbreviation Not Found");
                        }

                String sqlFind = "Select max(substring(`Vendor Code`, 3)) From `database`.`vendor_master`";
                try {
                    PreparedStatement pstFind = conn.prepareStatement(sqlFind);
                    ResultSet rs = pstFind.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()){
                     partNo = rs.getInt("Vendor Code")+1;
                        }}catch (Exception ex) {
                            partNo = 10001;
                     }


                String VendC = partCode+partNo;

                 try {
                     String sqlx = "SELECT `Abbreviation Use`, `Country English` From `database`.`country_master` " + 
                             "WHERE `Country English` = '" + Ctry + "'";
                     PreparedStatement pstx = conn.prepareStatement(sqlx);
                     ResultSet rs = pstx.executeQuery();
                     while (rs.next()){
                      CtryC = rs.getString("Abbreviation Use");
                        }}catch (Exception ex) {
                            System.out.println("Abbreviation Not Found");
                        }


                    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance(); //Get the current date
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                    String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
            //if 
            // 1.step: check if there are null values
            // 2.step: if there are no null values -> call frame "Confirm"
            // 3.step: if Confirm = true -> execute statement
            //         if Confitm = fals -> do nothing
                try {
                String sql = "INSERT INTO `database`.`vendor_master`(`Vendor Code`,`Vendor Full Name`,`Vendor Short Name`,"+
                                "`Address`,`Address Suffix`,`ZIP Code`,`City`,`Country`,`Country Code`,`UID No`,`Registration No`,"+
                                "`Payment Term`,`Creation Date`,`IBAN`,`BIC`,`Banking Institution`,`Representive`,`Email Address`,"+
                                "`Telefon No`,`Fax`,`Vendor Information`,`Active Flag`) "+
                                "Values('"+VendC+"','"+VendN+"','"+VendSN+"','"+Ad+"','"+Ads+"','"+Zip+"','"+City+"','"+Ctry+"','"+CtryC+"','"+
                                UID+"','"+Reg+"','"+PT+"','"+dateNow+"','"+Iban+"','"+Bic+"','"+BInst+"','"+Rep+"','"+Mail+"','"+Tel+"','"+
                                Fax+"','"+VendInfo+"','"+Flag+"')";


                    PreparedStatement pstExecute = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    pstExecute.execute();

                    System.out.println("Vendor Registered");

                    }catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println("Please insert required Fields!");
                    }

                ///end if
                }catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
            }
        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Show the code please!

Comment: I made a comment where I want to place this action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a JDialog instead:

```
int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (
                   null, 
                   "Are you sure you want to do that?",
                   "Warning",
                   JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if(dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    //Do a thing here
}
```

You can Take a look at the dialog here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

You can even extend JDialog instead if you want more functionality.